# go-plus atom package doesn't run goimports

Tags: go, ubuntu-16.04, atom-editor

This is my current version of

```
Atom    : 1.23.3
Electron: 1.6.15
Chrome  : 56.0.2924.87
Node    : 7.4.0
```

go-plus package is at

```
go-plus 5.8.1
```

I'm not quite sure how to about getting this to work or figuring out the issue

format box is check to run formattool on save and the formattool is set to  goimports

goimports work in my command line, so I suspect this is an issues with the package

I'm also using ubuntu 16.04, with kernel v 4.10. the newer updates doesn't detect any wifi devices

Comment: I've pretty much the exact same version numbers and config, just on macOS and this seems to work fine for me. Maybe Ubuntu related?

Comment: And this works fine for you?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned above, I don't experience any issues (on macOS).

Comment: I also have Ubuntu 16.04, and it works fine for me. What version of Go do you have? Is your `GOPATH` set properly? What is your `$GOPATH`? What is the output of `which goimports`?

Comment: So I believe it works now. I believe it is cause from using `direnv` to change my gopath dynamically. So I just made sure to update the packages within atom when I'm in a different directory.